# how to grep a particular pattern and particular content under that pattern in bash excluding all the other content in that file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a lib file,i want to grep a particular cell, pin and direction of that cell leaving out the other unwanted data of the other cell and there respective pin and direction. i have around 10 cells

**lib file**

```
macro cell A
class
origin
size
pin:sdf
direction:input
layer
port
end

macro cell B
class
origin
size
pin:vcc
direction:output
layer
port
end

macro cell C
class
origin
size
pin:vee
direction:inout
layer
port
end
```

output what i want

```
macro cell A
pin:sdf
direction:input
```

how can i do this

Comment: let me know if my answer solved your problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
macroToSelect="macro cell A"; 
awk -v var="$macroToSelect" '{if($0 == var){f=1;print}}/^pin:/{if(f)print}/^direction:/{if(f){print; exit}}' libfile
```

**output for your input:**

```
macro cell A
pin:sdf
direction:input
```

**explanations:**

- `-v var="$macroToSelect"` you pass the variable value to awk in order to select a specific macro cell
- `{if($0 == var){f=1;print}}` when the live is equal to the variable you passed you change `f` value to `1` by default it is at `0` and you print the line
- `/^pin:/{if(f)print}` whenever you meet a line that starts with `:pin` and if f is at 1 you print that line
- `/^direction:/{if(f){print; exit}` you do the same thing for `direction:` but this time you stop the execution of the command

**TESTED:**

[image]

if you want to print all the records with the pin and direction only then you can use:

```
 awk '/^(pin:|direction:|macro cell)/{print}' libfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution sir ,but can you tell me if i want all the 10  cells  output in the same pattern as cell name ,pin ,direction then how can i do it sir and is there any other simpler way than this .

Comment: then you can just remove the `"macro cell A"` into `"macro cell"` and remove the `exit` after the print and it should work! let me know if it solved your issue

Comment: sorry you should replace the exit by `f=0`

Comment: awk '/^(pin:|direction:|macro cell)/{print}' libfile =awk '/^(PIN |DIRECTION |MACRO)/{print}' lef but its just giving me the cell name no pin and direction list (small correction its just PIN no : its same with direction too )

Comment: grep -iE '^(macro|pin|direction)' lef
 this command is same as awk comand but its output is this macro cell ,A macro cell B ,macro cell c its only giving me the cell name but i also need pin and direction with the cell names

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `egrep` to separate the desired blocks based on "macro cell", then `egrep` again to get rid of unwanted fields:

```
egrep -A 5 'macro cell' input_file | egrep -iv 'origin|class|size'
```

You could also change the second part to only include the wanted fields:

```
egrep -A 5 'macro cell' input_file | egrep -i 'macro|pin|direction'
```

The `-A 5` prints 5 lines *after* the pattern. This works under the assumption that there is only one "macro cell A" in the file, and the blocks always have the same structure. Not pretty, but it works in this specific case.

Comment: But i have around 2000 lines in a file and around 25 cell with there respective pin and direction i want all the 25 cell with their respective pin and direction so how can i this method what you had posted will not work out sir can you suggest me a better way

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If you tweak my answer a bit it should work for the entire file. I edited my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi i am not able to find your edited answer can you send it again

Comment: It is in there. I just removed the `A` from the 'macro cell' , and it worked.